# Why my XML file with style sheet(XSL) can't be displayed first time loaded?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

The XML file with stylesheet (XSL) can be viewed at:

http://cistrome.org/cisapi/get/d2?id=2693

The problem is: In my browser(Firefox16), usually I need to **refresh** the page to see the whole page. Otherwise, I can only see a blank page without anything..

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

### Input document

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/cisapi_static/dataset2.xsl" ?>
<dataset>
    <id>2693</id>
    <treatment>
        <sample id="2112" mode="verbose">
            <factor>GATA2</factor>
            <datasetID>2693</datasetID>
            </cellLine>
            <cellType>Megakaryocytes</cellType>
            <cellPop>CD34+</cellPop>
            <species>Homo sapiens</species>
            <tissue>Bone Marrow</tissue>
            <diseaseState>Normal</diseaseState>
            </condition>
            <paper>Genome-wide analysis of simultaneous GATA1/2, RUNX1, FLI1, and SCL binding in megakaryocytes identifies hematopoietic regulators.</paper>
            <pmid>21571218</pmid>
            <authors>Tijssen MR,Cvejic A,Joshi A,Hannah RL,Ferreira R,Forrai A,Bellissimo DC,Oram SH,Smethurst PA,Wilson NK,Wang X,Ottersbach K,Stemple DL,Green AR,Ouwehand WH,Göttgens B</authors>
            <uniqueID>GSM607950</uniqueID>
            <url>ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByExp/sra/SRX/SRX029/SRX029434</url>
        </sample>
    </treatment>
    <control>
        <sample id="2951" mode="verbose">
            <factor>IgG</factor>
            </datasetID>
            </cellLine>
            <cellType>Megakaryocytes</cellType>
            <cellPop>CD34+</cellPop>
            <species>Homo sapiens</species>
            <tissue>Bone Marrow</tissue>
            <diseaseState>Normal</diseaseState>
            </condition>
            <paper>Genome-wide analysis of simultaneous GATA1/2, RUNX1, FLI1, and SCL binding in megakaryocytes identifies hematopoietic regulators.</paper>
            <pmid>21571218</pmid>
            <authors>Tijssen MR,Cvejic A,Joshi A,Hannah RL,Ferreira R,Forrai A,Bellissimo DC,Oram SH,Smethurst PA,Wilson NK,Wang X,Ottersbach K,Stemple DL,Green AR,Ouwehand WH,Göttgens B</authors>
            <uniqueID>GSM607954</uniqueID>
            <url>ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByExp/sra/SRX/SRX029/SRX029438</url>
        </sample>
    </control>
</dataset>
```

### Stylesheet

```
<!-- Edited with XML Spy v2007 (http://www.altova.com) -->
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body style="font-family:Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12pt; background-color:#EEEEEE">
        <div style="background-color:#FFFFF;color:black;padding:4px;text-align: center;">
            <b>Dataset </b select="dataset/id">
        </div>
        <xsl:for-each select="dataset/treatment/sample">
            <div style="background-color:#D8E3F9;color:black;padding:4px">
                <span style="font-weight:bold;color:black">         Sample <xsl:value-of select="@id" />: </span>
                <xsl:value-of select="factor" />
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#FFFFF;color:black;padding:20px">
              Uniqueid: <br select="uniqueID" />
              Factor: <br select="factor" />
              CellLine: <br select="cellLine" />
              Celltype: <br select="cellType" />
              Cellpop: <br select="cellPop" />
              Species: <br select="species" />
              Tissue: <br select="tissue" />
              Diseasestate: <br select="diseaseState" />
              Condition: </div select="condition">
            <div style="background-color:#FFFFF;color:black;padding:20px">
              Paper: <br select="paper" />
              Pmid: <br select="pmid" />
              Authors: <br select="authors" />
              Url: </div select="url">
            <br />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="dataset/control/sample">
            <div style="background-color:#86ABA5;color:black;padding:4px">
                <span style="font-weight:bold;color:black">     Sample <xsl:value-of select="@id" />: </span>
                <xsl:value-of select="factor" />
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#FFFFF;color:black;padding:20px">
              Uniqueid: <br select="uniqueID" />
              Factor: <br select="factor" />
              CellLine: <br select="cellLine" />
              Celltype: <br select="cellType" />
              Cellpop: <br select="cellPop" />
              Species: <br select="species" />
              Tissue: <br select="tissue" />
              Diseasestate: <br select="diseaseState" />
              Condition: </div select="condition">
            <div style="background-color:#FFFFF;color:black;padding:20px">
              Paper: <br select="paper" />
              Pmid: <br select="pmid" />
              Authors: <br select="authors" />
              Url: </div select="url">
            <br />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could not reproduce. Could this be a browser caching issue?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Maybe.. When I clear the cache, it work well by now

Answer (score 0):

Given the OP's comment, try: [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Insert these into the head.